# How to change values in a json file?

Tags: c++, json, qt

I have the following JSON-file :

```
{
    "users":[
        {"nom":"123",
        "name":"John",
        "family":"ala",
        "cash":1000
    }
    ,{"nom":"456",
        "name":"Joe",
        "family":"ala",
        "cash":1000
    }
    ,{"nom":"131",
        "name":"David",
        "family":"ala",
        "cash":1000
    }]
}
```

I would like to change `John`'s cash.

This is how I am trying to achieve this:

```
 QFile f("file address ...");
     f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text|QIODevice::WriteOnly);
       QByteArray b=f.readAll();
       QJsonDocument d=QJsonDocument::fromJson(b);
       QJsonObject o=d.object();

       for (int i=0;i<o["users"].toArray().size();i++) {
          if(o["users"].toArray()[i].toObject()["name"].toString()=="John")
          o["users"].toArray()[i].toObject()["cash"].toInt()=2000;//error unable to assign
            }
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> error: unable to assign

How to fix this?

Comment: use a lib and convert the string (deserialize) into a json object that you can access easily by key,value,index etc

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ the OP is doing exactly that with `QJsonDocument` and `QJsonObject`. The problem is, that this is how to read a value, not how to write it.

Comment: @Lily, you might want to take a look at the [JSON Save Game Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtcore-json-savegame-example.html).

Comment: Hint: remove `.toInt()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Cause

You get the error, because you are trying to assign a value to the return value of a function ([`QJsonValue::toInt`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#toInt) in this case).

### Solution

Assign the value to `QJsonValue`, as demonstrated in the [JSON Save Game Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-serialization-savegame-example.html):

```
void Character::write(QJsonObject &json) const
{
    json["name"] = mName;
    json["level"] = mLevel;
    json["classType"] = mClassType;
}
```

### Example

Here is an example I have written for you, in order to demonstrate how your code could be changed to implement the proposed solution:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile file("data.json");

    if (file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
        QJsonObject json = QJsonDocument::fromJson(file.readAll()).object();
        QJsonArray users = json["users"].toArray();

        file.close();

        for (auto user : users) {
            QJsonObject userObj = user.toObject();

            if (userObj["name"].toString() == "John")
                userObj["cash"] = 2000;

            user = userObj;
        }

        qDebug() << users;
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

### Result

The given example produces the following result:

```
QJsonArray([{"cash":2000,"family":"ala","name":"John","nom":"123"},{"cash":1000,"family":"ala","name":"Joe","nom":"456"},{"cash":1000,"family":"ala","name":"David","nom":"131"}])
```

Please note, that the `cash` for `John` is set to `2000`.