# Modify Json file in QT

Tags: json, qt

I have this JSON file in QT:

```
[
   {
     "name" : "Hussein",
     "age" : 20
   },
   {
     "name" : "Maria",
     "age" : 20
   },
]
```

I want to change the age of Hussein to 22. How can I do it in QT?

Comment: Did you try [QJsonDocument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change values in a json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63099530/how-to-change-values-in-a-json-file)